# Oracle synonym randomly not viewable

Tags: oracle, random, synonym

here's a tricky case on which 5 peoples including a DBA have been struggling on for days... I offer lifetime consideration to the one which will identify the root cause of the issue.

here it is:

Oracle Client: 10g
Oracle Server: 11g

We have 2 schemas and 1 user:

`SCHEMA1`

`SCHEMA2`

`USER`

We have 1 table `'TOTO'` which is defined in `SCHEMA1` (`SCHEMA1.TOTO`)
We have a private synonym of table `'TOTO'`, called `'TOTO'` defined in `SCHEMA2`, created like this:

`CREATE SYNONYM SCHEMA2.TOTO FOR SCHEMA1.TABLE1;`

We have granted SELECT,UPDATE,DELETE,INSERT priviledges on "SCHEMA2.TOTO " (so on the synonym) to SCHEMA2 (so that any session ran from SCHEMA2 has access to the synonym table)

`GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON SCHEMA2.TOTO TO SCHEMA2;`

Our application connects to the DB with `USER`, then directly switches to `SCHEMA2`:

`ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=SCHEMA2;`

Then after that, it tries to perform a select query on the synonym table WITHOUT prefixing the synonym name by SCHEMA1 (this is a constrain of the framework we use):

`SELECT COL FROM TOTO;`

Most of the times this query works successfully, which is what we expect since we have altered our session to `SCHEMA2`, by default that where the objects are looked.

But sometimes it fails, with an `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` error.

I insist on the fact that between the time when it works and when it fails, nothing has changed, we've just restarted the application (which is of course re-connecting to the DB the same way at each startup). 
We've been investigated with a DBA monitoring all the events on USER,SCHEMA1,SCHEMA2 hoping to find an external process modifying the GRANTS on one of thoses, between a success and a failure, but nothing changes. Yet, at some point, randomnly we get the ORA-00942 error, then we restart the application several times and it's back again...

Would someone have an idea or any suggestion/hint that could lead us to identify what we're missing here?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grant should go to `USER`, not to SCHEMA2:

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON schema1.toto TO userxy;
```

This should solve the problem. If it doesn't, can you please post the result of

```
SELECT * FROM all_objects WHERE object_name='TOTO';
```

Comment: This does seems to solve the issue, and make it clear how this should be done. Thanks! However I'm still having a hard time understanding why it works without it sometimes... obviously it shouldn't so there must be an external factor we haven't consider (probably on the tools and framework we use for our schema creation) which is messing with the GRANTs of USER.

Comment: You made sure the GRANTS don't change, so only three further suspects come to mind: 1) a changed PUBLIC SYNONYM which bypasses the name resolution, 2) a changed ROLE like DBA or SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE, which bypasses the grant system or 3) a changed connection AS SYSDBA. All three rather unlikely, though.